# Why OWL API's RDFXMLParser cannot resolve IRI with two hashes?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, iri

I am trying to load an ontology with OWL API.

one of the resources' IRI is `http://example.com/#1#2'`.

The following exception happens:

```
Parser: RDFXMLParser
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.syntax.RDFParserException: [line=129:column=52] IRI 'http://example.com/#1#2' cannot be resolved against curent base IRI http://example.com/ontology/demo.owl
```

If I change that IRI to `http://example.com/#1'`, then everything is fine.

**Why OWL API's RDFXMLParser cannot resolve IRI with two hashes?**

Answer (score 3):

`http://example.com/#1#2` isn't a legal IRI, so you shouldn't be able to treat is as one.  For instance, if you paste it into the [SPARQLer  IRI Validator](http://www.boinq.org/fuseki/iri-validator.html), you get the [output](http://www.boinq.org/fuseki/validate/iri?iri=http://example.com/#1#2):

> ### IRI Report
>
> `http://example.com/#1#2 ==> http://example.com/#1#2`
>   `<http://example.com/#1#2> Code: 0/ILLEGAL_CHARACTER in FRAGMENT: The
>   character violates the grammar rules for URIs/IRIs.`

If you created the ontology, then you need to be more careful about the IRIs that you're using.  If someone else created it, then you should let them know that they're producing bad data.  As a workaround, you might preprocess the ontology in some way to do something with these bad IRIs (e.g., URLencode the text after the first `#`).

Comment: The answer is spot on. However, the error reported makes me think the parser believes the IRI to be relative rather than wrong. There is probably a bug there, or at least a better error message to throw.

Comment: I wonder if it tries to treat it as absolute,  fails, and then assumes it must be relative?

Comment: That's possible. I've opened an issue to investigate https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues/71